# ChainLink general API get request Example not working

Tags: get, solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink

I'm developing a project with using a smartcontract that have to make an API call.
I'm tring to follow the ChainLink guide at this [link](https://docs.chain.link/getting-started/advanced-tutorial). I'd like to call the requestRiskData() from another function an than use the output (risk variable updated) to do some stuff. But since it takes like 30 seconds to update the risk value after the oracle call how i can wait to the risk variable to be updated?

Can someone send help?
Thx

I will attach the code here:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ConfirmedOwner.sol";

contract APIConsumer is ChainlinkClient, ConfirmedOwner {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

    uint256 public risk;
    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;
    string public a= "0x6e1db9836521977ee93651027768f7e0d5722a33";

    event RequestRisk(bytes32 indexed requestId, uint256 risk);

    /**
     * @notice Initialize the link token and target oracle
     *
     * Goerli Testnet details:
     * Link Token: 0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB
     * Oracle: 0xCC79157eb46F5624204f47AB42b3906cAA40eaB7 (Chainlink DevRel)
     * jobId: ca98366cc7314957b8c012c72f05aeeb
     *
     */

    constructor() ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender) {
        setChainlinkToken(0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB);
        setChainlinkOracle(0xCC79157eb46F5624204f47AB42b3906cAA40eaB7);
        jobId = "ca98366cc7314957b8c012c72f05aeeb";
        fee = (1 * LINK_DIVISIBILITY) / 10; // 0,1 * 10**18 (Varies by network and job)
    }
    // Set the path to find the desired data in the API response, where the response format is:
    // {
    //"data":{
    //  "0x6e1db9836521977ee93651027768f7e0d5722a33":{
    //      "risk":{
    //          "score":....
    //              }
    //      }
    //    }
    // }
    function requestRiskData() public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
        
        req.add("get","https://demo.anchainai.com/api/address_risk_score?proto=eth&address=0x6e1db9836521977ee93651027768f7e0d5722a33&apikey=demo_api_key");
        req.add("path", "data,0x6e1db9836521977ee93651027768f7e0d5722a33,risk,score");

        return sendChainlinkRequest(req, fee);
    }

    function fulfill(
        bytes32 _requestId,
        uint256 _risk
        
    ) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId) {
        emit RequestRisk(_requestId, _risk);
        risk = _risk;
    }

    function withdrawLink() public onlyOwner {
        LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(chainlinkTokenAddress());
        require(
            link.transfer(msg.sender, link.balanceOf(address(this))),
            "Unable to transfer"
        );
    }
    function myStuff() public payable{
    requestRiskData();
        if(risk>2){
           //DO MY STUFF
        }
    }

    }
```

I tried to write the myStuff() function but i don't know how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clarify what you mean by "I'd like to call the requestRiskData() from another function an than use the output (risk variable updated) to do some stuff"

When you say "use the output to do some stuff" do you mean outside the contract (front end) or from inside the smart contract?

If you want to use the value of `_risk` returned by the oracle, you should just add that logic (or call a helper function that implements that logic) after the value of `_risk` is set in your `fulfill()` callback.

so in your case, the following lines should be moved into the end of the `fulfill()` callback:

```
if(risk>2){
           //DO MY STUFF
        }
```

If you're using the value of `_risk` from the front end, then use ethersjs or web3js to listen for the `RequestRisk` event in your front end.

On a side note, you may want to consider renaming that event as its not in the request function but in the callback, so its really should be a `RiskReceived` or event of that sort of name.

hope this helps!